# Lightmaps from RTCW BSP file not being rendered correctly

Tags: c++, lightmap, quake3, binary-space-partitioning

I'm trying to recreate a Return To Castle Wolfenstein renderer using Direct3D 11, but I can't seem to be able to render the lightmaps as they should be. I have not found much information on the internet on how Quake3/RTCW lightmaps are actually created from the BSP files. Basically, the result is as below:

[image: Lightmaps not scaled right]

And this is how the result should be:

[image: Correct lightmap display]

With the info taken from [Q3 BSP file format](http://www.mralligator.com/q3/), I extracted the lightmap x and y origin inside the lightmap data taken from the lightmap index lmindex, in the BSP file from lm_start[0] and lm_start[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ZO2.png) and the width and height from lm_size[0] and lm_size[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ZO2.png). The problem seems to be in finding the lightmap texture coordinates, which I assumed were the same as the face textures. After each lightmap extracted, I assigned the lightmap index to the face index. A negative index indicates that no lightmap is associated to the face.

Here is the code I used to create lightmaps from the file:

```
bool XWorldMap::CreateLightmaps(ID3D11Device* pd3d, ID3D11DeviceContext* 
pd3dDeviceContext)
{
    m_lightMaps.reserve(m_numFaces);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_numFaces; ++i)
    {
        ID3D11ShaderResourceView* pTexture = nullptr;
        int x = m_q3Faces[i].lmstart[0];
        int y = m_q3Faces[i].lmstart[1];
        int lightMapWidth = m_q3Faces[i].lmsize[0];
        int lightMapHeight = m_q3Faces[i].lmsize[1];
        int lightMapIndex = m_q3Faces[i].lmindex;
        m_q3Faces[i].lmindex = (lightMapIndex < 0) ? -1 : i;

        if (lightMapIndex < 0 || lightMapWidth == 0 || lightMapHeight == 0)
        {
            m_lightMaps.push_back(nullptr);
            continue;
        }

        std::vector<char> lightMapData;
        lightMapData.reserve(4*lightMapHeight*lightMapWidth);

        for (int j = y; j < y + lightMapHeight; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = x; k < x + lightMapWidth; ++k)
            {
                lightMapData.push_back(m_q3LightMaps[lightMapIndex].map[j][k][0]);
                lightMapData.push_back(m_q3LightMaps[lightMapIndex].map[j][k][1]);
                lightMapData.push_back(m_q3LightMaps[lightMapIndex].map[j][k][2]);
                lightMapData.push_back(255);
            }
        }

        if (!CreateTexture(pd3d, pd3dDeviceContext, lightMapData, lightMapHeight, lightMapWidth, &pTexture))
            return false;

        m_lightMaps.push_back(pTexture);
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is the code to create the lightmap textures:

```
bool CreateTexture(ID3D11Device* pd3d, ID3D11DeviceContext* 
pd3dDeviceContext, std::vector<char> imgData, unsigned int height, unsigned 
int width, ID3D11ShaderResourceView ** pTexture)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    ID3D11Texture2D *pTex2D = nullptr;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    texDesc.Width = width;
    texDesc.Height = height;
    texDesc.MipLevels = texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    hr = pd3d->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, nullptr, &pTex2D);

    if (FAILED(hr))
       return false;

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE  mappedTex;
    pd3dDeviceContext->Map(pTex2D, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, 
    &mappedTex);

    UCHAR* pTexels = (UCHAR*)mappedTex.pData;
    int j = 0;
    for (UINT row = 0; row < texDesc.Height; row++)
    {
        UINT rowStart = row * mappedTex.RowPitch;
        for (UINT col = 0; col < texDesc.Width; col++)
        {
            UINT colStart = col * 4;
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = imgData[j++];
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = imgData[j++];
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = imgData[j++];
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = imgData[j++];
        }
    }

    pd3dDeviceContext->Unmap(pTex2D, D3D11CalcSubresource(0,0,1));

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
    memset(&srvDesc, 0, sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    hr = pd3d->CreateShaderResourceView(pTex2D, &srvDesc, pTexture);

    if (FAILED(hr))
       return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the RTCW source code? https://github.com/id-Software/RTCW-SP - lightmap loading in particular is here: https://github.com/id-Software/RTCW-SP/blob/master/src/renderer/tr_bsp.c#L141

Comment: No, I have not. I will look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem seems to be in finding the lightmap texture coordinates, which I assumed were the same as the face textures.

They're not.

If we examine the [RTCW source code](https://github.com/id-Software/RTCW-SP), paying particular attention to the [ParseTriSurf function](https://github.com/id-Software/RTCW-SP/blob/master/src/renderer/tr_bsp.c#L492), we see the [code for loading lightmap texture coordinates](https://github.com/id-Software/RTCW-SP/blob/master/src/renderer/tr_bsp.c#L533) is as follows:

```
    for ( j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++ ) {
        tri->verts[i].st[j] = LittleFloat( verts[i].st[j] );
        tri->verts[i].lightmap[j] = LittleFloat( verts[i].lightmap[j] );
    }
```

And [the drawVert_t structure](https://github.com/id-Software/RTCW-SP/blob/70951bc71b730efe6bcb07db7ae76ef0c4ae7c14/src/qcommon/qfiles.h#L687) is:

```
typedef struct {
    vec3_t xyz;
    float st[2];
    float lightmap[2];
    vec3_t normal;
    byte color[4];
} drawVert_t;
```

Here, "st" is the standard OpenGL convention for diffuse texture coordinates (Direct3D typically uses "uv") so we can see that lightmap texture coordinates follow them in the struct.

Comment: Figured it out in the end, the lightmap coordinates were stored in the BSP vertices, not in the faces. Everything works now. Wonder how I could have missed that earlier.